# How to read bytes from file using std::ifstream to std::array?

Tags: c++, fstream, stdarray

The below program tries to open a rom file and loads it to `std::array`.

```
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const std::string ROM_FILE = "cpu_instrs.gb";

int main()
{
    std::array<uint8_t, 0x8000> m_Cartridge;
    std::ifstream istream(ROM_FILE, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    
    istream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t length = istream.tellg();
    istream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    
    if (length > m_Cartridge.size())
    {
        length = m_Cartridge.size();
    }
    
    istream.read(m_Cartridge.data(), length);
    
    for (const uint8_t& b : m_Cartridge)
    {
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran the program above using g++, I got the following error

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:21:34: error: invalid conversion from 'std::array<unsigned char, 32768>::pointer' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'std::basic_istream<char>::char_type*' {aka 'char*'} [-fpermissive]
   21 |     istream.read(m_Cartridge.data(), length);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
      |                                  |
      |                                  std::array<unsigned char, 32768>::pointer {aka unsigned char*}
In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/fstream:38,
                 from test.cpp:2:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/istream:486:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type = char; std::streamsize = long long int]'
  486 |       read(char_type* __s, streamsize __n);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

It seems to me that `std::istream` only works with `char` not `unsigned char`. When I change type from `uint8_t` to `char`. The program compiles and ran without problems. Is there any way to make `std::istream` work with `uint8_t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::istream` is written in terms of `char_type` being simply `char`, and similarly, [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) is the same.

The *conventional* approach would be to `reinterpret_cast<char*>` the pointer that you are reading to:

```cpp
istream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_Cartridge.data()), length);
```

Although using `reinterpret_cast` is often frowned upon in many cases, this is one such case where it's both necessary and also safe to perform, since pointers to `char` are capable of aliasing any object with the same reachability as the parent object (in this case, the same reachability as the entire `array` object).

In fact, if you check the [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) page on cppreference, even it uses a similar example to read the raw binary:

```cpp
std::uint32_t n;
if(raw.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof n)) { ... }
```

---

That said, there is technically an alternative way you can do this -- though it's not recommended. The various `stream` classes are templated on the character type (`basic_*stream<...>`), of which `std::ifstream` is an alias of. Technically you could try to instantiate `std::basic_ifstream<unsigned char>` and `read` from this without a cast. However, in doing so, you may need to implement a custom [`std::char_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) -- as this is not required by the C++ standard to work with `signed` or `unsigned` character types (e.g. `std::char_traits<unsigned char>` is not guaranteed to be valid)